# Django CSRF verification failed even with @csrf_exempt

Tags: django, csrf

I've got a web service written in Django that has a py file with a bunch of view functions that are decorated with @csrf_exempt.  It's all working as it has been for years.  I recently added another function and entry in urls.py.  I used the same pattern as all the other view functions -- decorated with @csrf_exempt, but for this one function the server responds with a CSRF verification failed.

a snippet of my urls.py

```
    url(r'changepassword$', websvc2_account.changepassword),
    url(r'resetpassword$', websvc2_account.resetpassword),
    url(r'getcodetodeleteaccount$', websvc2_account.getcodetodeleteaccount),
    url(r'deleteaccountwithcode$', websvc2_account.deleteaccountwithcode),
    url(r'setuserdetails$', websvc2_account.setuserdetails),
```

The function I added:

```
@csrf_exempt
def getcodetodeleteaccount(request):
    ...
```

These views are called from mobile apps, so I do not want CSRF and all of them are decorated with @csrf_exempt.  This new function is the only one that doesn't work.

Any help or clues would be appreciated.
Thanks